# How to correctly echo database results from checkbox form with submit button into table?

Tags: php, html, mysql, database

Hello everyone I'm new to php, mysql, and html and for a project I'm working on have a simple database with id, product, price, and condition. On my html form I have four checkboxes with ranges of prices 0-25, 25-50, 50-75, and 75-100. Here's an example of what I'm trying to do: if the user selects the checkbox with 0-25, it's supposed to echo the id, product, price, and condition of all products that cost 0-25 in a table.I have the checkbox values saved in an array, but I'm completely lost at this point. How can I output values in my database of the checkbox checked.

P.S. I've heard of PDO, but we have to use mysql for this project. 
Here's my html:

```
<form action="pricefilter.php" method="post">
<br><b>Filter By Price:</b><br><br> 
<input type="checkbox" name="priceFilter[]" id="Price" value="025"/>&nbsp;$0-$25<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="priceFilter[]" id="Price" value="2550"/>&nbsp;$25-$50<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="priceFilter[]" id="Price" value="5075"/>&nbsp;$50-$75<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="priceFilter[]" id="Price" value="75100"/>&nbsp;$75-$100<br><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="priceFilter[]" id="Price" value="100"/>&nbsp;$75-$100<br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Here is my php:

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","root")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("XUSWAPSAMPLE");

$priceFilter = $_GET['priceFilter'];

 $filteredResponse = array ();
foreach($priceFilter as $range)
{
if($range == 025)
    {
        $query = "select * from Books where Price <= 25";
        $sql = mysql_query($query);

        array_push($filteredResponse, $sql);

    }

    if($range == 2550)
    {
        $query = "select * from Books where Price >= 25 AND Price <=50";
        $sql = mysql_query($query);

        array_push($filteredResponse, $sql);
    }
     if($range == 5075)
    {
        $query = "select * from Books where Price >= 50 AND Price <=75";
        $sql = mysql_query($query);

        array_push($filteredResponse, $sql);
    }

     if($range == 75100)
    {
        $query = "select * from Books where Price >= 75 AND Price <=100";
        $sql = mysql_query($query);

        array_push($filteredResponse, $sql);
    }
     if($range == 100)
    {
        $query = "select * from Books where Price >= 100";
        $sql = mysql_query($query);

        array_push($filteredResponse, $sql);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things wrong in your code

1) You are using post method submit form but trying to get value using $_GET, hence you should use $_POST

2) You should use isset property of php to check if values exist or not.

So the solution is try this

```
if (isset($_POST['priceFilter']) && ($_POST['priceFilter']!="")) {
    $priceFilter = $_POST['priceFilter'];

    // put your remaining code here
}
```